# PHP : How to lock an active directory user account?

Tags: php, active-directory

i've a working script that allow me to unlock a user account (by setting lockouttime AD attribute to 0)
something like this :

```
$entry["lockouttime"][0]=0;
$mod=ldap_mod_replace($ds,$dn,$entry)
```

Now I'd like to do the opposite : lock the account.
I've read that ***lockouttime is a system attribute and active directory will not allow us to set its value to something else that 0.***

So i'm trying to bind to the server with the user account and a bad password, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){   
    ldap_bind($ds,$dn, "theWrongPasswd");
}
```

running this will show this error

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

but the account is still unlock.

Do you have any idea on how can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

LDAP bind attempts don't count as logon attempts.  Using APIs like [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CreateProcessWithLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) generate logon attempts.

Comment: How can I use these functions un PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Locking the user via the `userAccountControl`'s `LOCKOUT` Flag (`0x0010`) is **not possible**. This flag is related to the AD's password policy and will be set **by the system** if there are too many login attempts. I've tried it myself: After setting the flag and commiting the changes to the AD the changes, the value did not change - no Exception was thrown.

Disabling an account will propably achieve the same thing you want to do. For this you will have to set the `ACCOUNTDISABLE` Flag (`0x0002`).

This is the list of all UAC flags: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144 suggests that a normal account will have a value of 512 for their UAC.

> LOCKOUT   0x0010  16
>   NORMAL_ACCOUNT    0x0200  512

I believe that setting it to 528 (lockout + normal account) will lock the users account.

```
$entry["userAccountControl"][0]=512;
$mod=ldap_mod_replace($ds,$dn,$entry);
```

Comment: This is not working with the lockout flag. The system doesnt let me set a value of 528 (thus it shows no error). This must be a special flag, because it is working with the flag "disable" (2) ...

Comment: Accounts cannot be locked by user, they can only be unlocked. If you try setting this flag (By modifying LDAP attribute) it will not display any error but the value will reamin unchanged. But the vice-versa is true, if your account is indeed lockedout (has value 528) you can set it to `512` (By modifying LDAP attribute) and in this case it will reflect the new value and account will get unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend counting failed bind attempts yourself using the a session variable and locking the account yourself based on that.

To lock the account, you'll need to cumulate user account control options and set the UserAccountControl attribute.

Referencing http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144, locking would be:

```
$controlOption["useraccountcontrol"][0] = '514';
$mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $controlOption);
```

The 514 value coming from NORMAL_ACCOUNT(512) + ACCOUNTDISABLE(2).

Unlocking would be a value of NORMAL_ACCOUNT, 512.

Final code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $result = ldap_bind($ds, $dn, "theWrongPasswd");

    if (!$result) {
        $_SESSION['failed-login']++;
    }

    if ($_SESSION['failed-login'] >= $maxCount) {
        $controlOption["useraccountcontrol"][0] = 512 + 2;
        $mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $controlOption);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

To unlock:

```
$acctEntry["lockouttime"][0] = '1';
$mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $acctEntry);
```

To lock:

```
$acctEntry["lockouttime"][0] = '0';
$mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $acctEntry);
```

To enable:

```
$acctEntry["useraccountcontrol"][0] = '512';
$mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $acctEntry);
```

To disable:

```
$acctEntry["useraccountcontrol"][0] = '514';
$mod = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $acctEntry);
```

Comment: I dont want to disable user, lock it. You inverse locking and unlocking in your answer, You didnt read my question it said we cant put anyting else than 0 in lockouttime

Comment: I'm providing examples of lock & unlock and enable & disable account. It's not meant to be a straight copy & paste the entire codes into your script. Use only the one that you require. :)